# Angularjs - ng-disabled default value

Tags: angularjs

I have a button with this attribute: `ng-disabled="ProductionBtnDisabled"`.

When angular renders the html the value of `ProductionBtnDisabled` is undefined and after initiating the controller `ProductionBtnDisabled` has the correct value.

So, at first the `ng-disabled` is not disabled because `undefined=false` in javascript/angular. This is a problem for me. I want the default value to be true.

Is any one has any suggestion to handle this?

What about using `ng-cloak`? It didn't work for me. I don't mind hiding the buttons until the scope is rendered.

Thanks!

Comment: ng-disabled="ProductionBtnDisabled || ProductionBtnDisabled===undefined".

Comment: That is not good. I want a global solution and not on every button to do that.

Comment: Can you show some code?  How does the value get set in your controller?  A code example that shows the problem would be perfect.

Comment: HTML : <button ng-disabled="tpPrint.ProductionBtnDisabled" type="button" class="top-btn btn navbar-btn productionButton">Process Now</button>
      
Controller : tpObj.ProductionBtnDisabled = tpObj.isProductionDisabled();

Comment: tpObj.isProductionDisabled() has an Ajax call also.

Comment: do : button ng-disabled="!tpPrint.ProductionBtnDisabled".. it will work..

Comment: i mean put  ! operator, it will work for you..

Comment: Is there any angular solution to this kind of problem? Like ng-cloak?

Comment: The operator ! will not work. It will do the opposite when I have the correct value.

Comment: ya.. that is the logic.. try it.. It will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no default settings for ngDisabled. If you needs a global solution, you can try directive.

```
.directive('specialDisabled',function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:{specialDisabled: '='},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function(){return scope.specialDisabled}, function(){
          // set disabled attribute here
          element[0].disabled = !scope.specialDisabled;  
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Then, you can called specialDisabled directive anywhere.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk">
<button special-disabled="chk">My Button</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BA2ntTrzmItwvEj8UKOc?p=preview